# Where are the File Manager settings stored on the disk?

Tags: raspbian, settings

I am trying to set up a large number (30) of headless  Raspberries and I want to change (turn off) the "Show available options..." setting of the File Manager.

I know how to do it form the GUI, from the PCManFM of the File Manager, but I want to do it from the command line (or changing the file that holds the setting).

What is the command to change this or (even better) what is the file that holds this setting of the File Manager?

GUI way:

[image]

Comment: On my PiOS 64-bit the pcmanfm config is in ~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE-pi/pcmanfm.conf. No idea if that setting is actually in that file

Comment: *"the PCManFM of the File Manager"* -> Just in case there is some confusion: PCManFM **is** the "File Manager".

Comment: @Dirk 
Nothing there. 
Not even in the /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE* dirs...

pcmanfm has some options, but didn't find anything even remote relevant...

Comment: It's the 'autostart' entry in the [Volumes] section in pcmanfm.conf

Comment: All the pcmanfm.conf (that are anywhere) hav only this:
[volume]
mount_on_startup=1
mount_removable=1
autorun=1

And none of those change when I change the setting from the GUI (so that's not it...).

Comment: check the timestamps of all the files in your home directory and in its subdirectories .... you should really be asking this at a linux site

Comment: You confuse me by saying your Pi's are headless, then asking a question about a GUI. What OS are you using, is it the Lite version?

Comment: No its the normal OS version, but I want to execute a script from the inserted USB without the intervention of a user. The USB will be inserted (by a janitor) and removed in 1 minute. Everything works perfectly as long as I have manually changed that setting in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work in my Raspberry Pi OS.

File content of `~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE-pi/pcmanfm.conf` is:-

```
[config]
bm_open_method=0

[volume]
mount_on_startup=0
mount_removable=0
autorun=0

[ui]
always_show_tabs=0
max_tab_chars=32
win_width=943
win_height=653
splitter_pos=288
media_in_new_tab=0
desktop_folder_new_win=0
change_tab_on_drop=1
close_on_unmount=1
focus_previous=0
side_pane_mode=dirtree
view_mode=list
show_hidden=0
show_thumbs=0
sort=name;ascending;
columns=name;size;mtime;
toolbar=newtab;navigation;home;
show_statusbar=1
pathbar_mode_buttons=0
prefs_app=SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/pipanel/pwdpip.sh pipanel
common_bg=0
```

The relevant command is `autorun=0`
NOTE the file does not exist unless you save changes (although you could copy the default) `/etc/xdg/pcmanfm/default/pcmanfm.conf` or `/etc/xdg/pcmanfm/LXDE-pi/pcmanfm.conf`.

Comment: Yup, thats it! Thanks! The only problem is that the value does not "stick". If you change it and go to look for the change in the GUI it reverts back, but thats not a big problem, a reboot will fix it.